# c# HwndSourceHook with Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, hwnd

i found this code:

> ```
>     protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
>     {
>         base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
>         HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
>
>         if (hwndSource != null)
>         {
>             installedHandle = hwndSource.Handle;
>             viewerHandle = SetClipboardViewer(installedHandle);
>             hwndSource.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.hwndSourceHook));
>         }
>     }
> ```

to start a hwndSourceHook (to capture the clipboard). But this code only works with a "Window" but not with a "Windows.Form".

How i can get the hwndSource of my Form to add the hwndSourceHook?

(instead of the override I should use the Form_Load function I think...)

**EDIT: Thanks, but the Form doesnt have the AddHook function to add my hwndSourceHook**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, then it is just myForm.Handle

The HwndSource is for WPF.

So you can just do:

```
viewerHandle = SetClipboardViewer(myForm.Handle);
```

Edit: AddHook is also a WPF method.

You need to use either:

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(...);
```

or, in your Form class override the WndProc method:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {...}
```

AddMessageFilter can capture messages for any window in your application, whereas WndProc will only receive messages for the given window.